# Rebus 4.0 - How to specify order of handlers , tried with "SpecifyOrderOfHandlers" method but gives compile time error

Tags: rebus

Hellooo Rebus Fans, We have been using Rebus 0.84 aka 1.0 for many years and now **moving to 4.0 version** & it seems its improved a lot in terms of implementation & performance but facing some problems while **implementing orders for handlers**.

Example in previous version , we used to do

```
public class RebusInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        Configure.With(new WindsorContainerAdapter(container))
      .Logging(l => l.Log4Net())
      .Transport(t => t.UseMsmqAndGetInputQueueNameFromAppConfig())
      .SpecifyOrderOfHandlers(t => t.First<AuthenticationHandler>())
      .Serialization(x => x.UseJsonSerializer())
      .MessageOwnership(m => m.FromRebusConfigurationSection())
      .Sagas(m => m.StoreInNDb())
      .Subscriptions(m => m.StoreInNDb())
      .Timeouts(m => m.StoreInMemory())
      .Events(e =>
      {
          e.MessageSent += (advancedbus, destination, message) =>
          {
              var timeToBeReceived = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeToBeReceived"];
              if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(timeToBeReceived))
                  timeToBeReceived = "00:00:30";
              if (timeToBeReceived != "-1")
              {
                  advancedbus.AttachHeader(message, Headers.TimeToBeReceived, timeToBeReceived);
                  advancedbus.AttachHeader(message, Headers.Express, "rebus-express");
              }
          };
      })
      .CreateBus()
      .Start();
    }
}
```

and now if i am implementing the same with rebus 4.0 then somehow , while trying "SpecifyOrderOfHandlers" it gives compile time error that it does not accept any argument then how can we implement ordering of handlers, below is the implementation with rebus 4.0

```
using Rebus.Config;
using Rebus.Persistence.InMem;
using Rebus.Handlers;
using Rebus.Messages;

public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        Configure.With(new CastleWindsorContainerAdapter(container))
          .Options(o =>
          {
              o.SpecifyOrderOfHandlers(o => o.First<AuthenticationHandler>());
          })
          .Logging(l => l.Log4Net())
          .Transport(t => t.UseMsmq(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputQueue"]))
          .Routing(r => r.TypeBasedRoutingFromAppConfig())
          .Sagas(m => m.StoreInNDb())
          .Subscriptions(m => m.StoreInNDb())
          .Timeouts(m => m.StoreInMemory())
          .Events(e =>
          {
              e.BeforeMessageSent += (bus, headers, message, context) =>
              {
                  var timeToBeReceived = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeToBeReceived"];
                  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(timeToBeReceived))
                      timeToBeReceived = "00:00:30";
                  if (timeToBeReceived != "-1")
                  {
                      headers.Add(Headers.TimeToBeReceived, timeToBeReceived);
                      headers.Add(Headers.Express, "rebus-express");
                  }
              };
          })
          .Start();
    }
```

Please suggest how to implement handler ordering with rebus 4.0 and also let me know if above approach of implementing rebus 4.0 is correct or needs improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've simply made the call to `SpecifyOrderOfHandlers` a little bit too complicated – this should do the trick:

```
Configure.With(activator)
    (...)
    .Options(o =>
    {
        o.SpecifyOrderOfHandlers()
            .First<AuthenticationHandler>();
    })
    .(...)
    .Start();
```

If it wasn't readily obvious, then it's probably because the `SpecifyOrderOfHandlers` is in another namespace, so if you add

```
using Rebus.Handlers.Reordering;
```

in the top of your file somewhere, then I bet IntelliSense will guide you :)

Comment: Thanks !! It worked ! And I had already used the namespace "Rebus.Handlers.Reordering" so only part bothering me was the way to implement SpecifyOrderOfHandlers :) 

Actually I looked into github wiki (https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Handler-pipeline) for implementation & there it was showing the way I implemented earlier so it was confusing for me.